# Giving span content index number of parent 'li'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am trying to add content to the span dynamically via jquery. Span is inside a unordered list. I want to add the index number of each li to the span so it would look like this:

- Provider 1
- Provider 2
- Provider 3

how would I resolve this issue

**but currently, it's doing this**

- Provider 1
- Provider 1
- Provider 1

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {


 var timesClickedIndex = $('.timesClicked').closest("li").index() + 1;
 $('.timesClicked').html('Providor '+timesClickedIndex);
  
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>

<div>
<span class="timesClicked"></span>
</div>

</li>
<li>

<div>
<span class="timesClicked"></span>
</div>

</li>
<li>

<div>
<span class="timesClicked"></span>
</div>

</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have to ask, why not fix the logic that creates the markup in the first place, rather than band-aid'ing it with javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following (which uses index on [jquery each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)).

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
 $('.timesClicked').each(function(i,e) { $(e).html('Providor '+ (i+1)); });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>
<div>
<span class="timesClicked"></span>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div>
<span class="timesClicked"></span>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div>
<span class="timesClicked"></span>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

The reason your code doesn't work is because index() as you are using it will always yield 1 and you are simply applying that single value to all elements.  You could use index() as in the following example, but the code is too convoluted then the example above:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  $('.timesClicked').each(function(i,e) { 
    $(e).html('Providor '+ ($('.timesClicked').index(e) + 1)); 
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>
<div>
<span class="timesClicked"></span>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div>
<span class="timesClicked"></span>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div>
<span class="timesClicked"></span>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the each jquery function to do this.
https://api.jquery.com/each/

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {


 var timesClickedIndex = $('.timesClicked').each(function( index ) 
        {
            $(this).html('Providor ' + (index + 1)); 
        });      
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>

<div>
<span class="timesClicked"></span>
</div>

</li>
<li>

<div>
<span class="timesClicked"></span>
</div>

</li>
<li>

<div>
<span class="timesClicked"></span>
</div>

</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over the spans using `.each()` and use the index argument to number them with:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('.timesClicked').each(function(i) {
    $(this).html('Providor ' + (i+1));
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>

    <div>
      <span class="timesClicked"></span>
    </div>

  </li>
  <li>

    <div>
      <span class="timesClicked"></span>
    </div>

  </li>
  <li>

    <div>
      <span class="timesClicked"></span>
    </div>

  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  $('.timesClicked').each(function(key){
    $(this).html('Providor '+ (key+1));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li>
  <div>
    <span class="timesClicked"></span>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <div>
    <span class="timesClicked"></span>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <div>
    <span class="timesClicked"></span>
  </div>
 </li>
</ul>
```